# How to get PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_REMOTE_HOLD in pjsip

Tags: android, pjsip

I'm working on PJSIP Android app and facing a problem with call hold. While the caller is call to the receiver when caller is put call on hold, receiver how can identify is remote server call on hold? Which event is occurs in receiver hand?

Comment: did u fix dat problem??

Comment: not yet, if you found some please share with us

Comment: caller and callee are both parties pjsip android apps??

Comment: yes both on pjsip

Answer (score 1):

According to pjsip docs:

> `virtual void onCallMediaState(OnCallMediaStateParam &prm)`
>
> Notify application when media state in the call has changed.

Normal application would need to implement this callback, e.g. to connect the call’s media to sound device.

This method is in Call class in pjsip java:
`CallMediaInfo` class contains `pjsua_call_media_status`.
Using pjsua_call_media_status we can know whether current call media status is active or is on call hold.

```
@Override
    public void onCallMediaState(OnCallMediaStateParam prm)
    {
    CallInfo ci;
    try {
        ci = getInfo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
    
    CallMediaInfoVector cmiv = ci.getMedia();
    CallMediaInfo callMediaInfo = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < cmiv.size(); i++) {
        CallMediaInfo cmi = cmiv.get(i);
        if (cmi.getType() == pjmedia_type.PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO &&
        (cmi.getStatus() == 
            pjsua_call_media_status.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_REMOTE_HOLD ||
         cmi.getStatus() == 
            pjsua_call_media_status.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_LOCAL_HOLD) )
        {
            //set ur call status  as hold on your TextView 
        }else if (cmi.getType() == pjmedia_type.PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO &&
        (cmi.getStatus() == 
            pjsua_call_media_status.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE))
            {
                //set ur call status  as connected on your TextView 
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: not working dude theoretical bate mat kr we practical

Comment: @SuryaPrakashKushawah if possible can see your class where you add this code??

Comment: no bro i have already tried above code. PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_REMOTE_HOLD variable is give your result. you can say its return true while you self put call on hold. We can listen hold music but we cant receive any kind of event in other  end